# Why is transferring large local files in PowerShell so slow for me

Tags: windows, powershell, files

I am currently using PowerShell's `Copy-Item` commandlet to create a copy of a 500GB file and transferring it to another local hard drive on the computer. Doing it this way is really slow: a couple hours for it to finish. When I simply right-click the file, select copy, and paste, the transfer takes about an hour. Is there another PowerShell cmdlet to use to get faster transfer time?

EDIT:
Powershell commandlet iam currently using `Copy-Item -Path G:\Backups  -Destination I:\Backups  -Force -Recurse`

Comment: Please share the actual commands that you are running. Are you making a copy of the file and then moving that copy, or just using one instance of the Copy-Item cmdlet to create your copy?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another PowerShell cmdlet to use to get faster transfer time?

It's slow because it is using buffered I/O. If you want performance parity use a native Windows command such as XCOPY or RoboCopy and use unbuffered I/O.

Comment: yep robocopy helped alot in transfer time thanks

Comment: Any ideas why the native windows command is not the default in PowerShell on a Windows system?